# Multiple Input selection in Rshiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity

I am trying to build a Rshiny for my project. I am trying to include 2 inputs,
First Input is a dropdown which contains months from Jan-Dec.
Second input can be a drop down or anything that allows me to select multiple items. Second input items are something like -"Assault","Theft","Burglary" etc..
A user can choose only one item from  First Input and multiple items from Second input.
So Basically If I choose Jan from first input and "Assault","Theft" from second input a bar graph depicting the no of Assault and Theft In jan should show up.

Input dataframe looks like this 

`PrimaryType    Month    count
Assault         Jan      25
Burglary        Jan      30
Tresspass       Feb      23
Assault         Feb      12
Burglary        Feb      34`

```
ui <- fluidPage(


 titlePanel(div(HTML("<em> Crime Rate in Chichago </em>"))),

  tabsetPanel(



  tabPanel(" Frequency of Crime ",
         sidebarLayout(

           sidebarPanel(

             #First Input#

             selectInput(inputId = "Month",
                         label = " Choose a Month",
                         choices = unique(crime$Month))),

           #Second input#
           selectInput(inputId = "Crime",
                       label = " Choose among Crime",
                       choices = unique(crime$`Primary Type`),multiple = 
TRUE)),

         #Output#

           mainPanel = (plotOutput("view")
           )
         )
  )
  )


  #Shiny app -Server#
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$view <- renderPlot({
  Monthfilter <- a[a$Month==input$Month,]

crimefilter <- Monthfilter[Monthfilter$`Primary Type` %in% input$Crime,]

ggplot(crimefilter, aes(`Primary Type`,c))+geom_bar(stat="identity")
  })
}

#Shinyapp#
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I would like a bar graph for a particular month with multiple Primary Types of crime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the future, try and provide some example data in your code so it does not have to be reproduced.

Here are a few errors in your code:

- mainPanel should fall within sidebarLayout
- Your dataset is 'crime' not 'a' as you have put in your plot output (a[a$Month==input$Month,])
- You may have set your column header as 'PrimaryType' in your dataset but you have referenced it in your code as 'Primary Type' (with a space)

```
crime = data.table('Primary Type' = c('Assault','Burglary', 'Tresspass', 'Assault','Burglary'),
                   Month = c('Jan', 'Jan', 'Feb','Feb','Feb'),
                   Count = c(12,13,43,54,11))

ui <- fluidPage(


  titlePanel(div(HTML("<em> Crime Rate in Chichago </em>"))),

  tabsetPanel(



    tabPanel(" Frequency of Crime ",
             sidebarLayout(

               sidebarPanel(
                 #First Input#

                 selectInput(inputId = "Month",
                             label = " Choose a Month",
                             choices = unique(crime$Month)),

                 #Second input#
                 selectInput(inputId = "Crime",
                             label = " Choose among Crime",
                             choices = unique(crime$`Primary Type`),
                             multiple = TRUE)
                 ),

               #Output#

               mainPanel(
                 plotOutput("bar_plot")
               )

              )


    )
  )
)


#Shiny app -Server#
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$bar_plot <- renderPlot({
    Monthfilter <- crime[crime$Month == input$Month,]
    print('hello')
    crimefilter <- Monthfilter[Monthfilter$`Primary Type` %in% input$Crime,]

    ggplot(data = crimefilter, aes(x = `Primary Type`, y = Count)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
  })
}

#Shinyapp#
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)r)
```